# how to upgrade pc from usb 1.1 to usb 3.0

Tags: usb

Is this possible?

There is a good chance I do not have USB 2.0

This is a HPXW8400 Workstation

Do I just install a PCIE usb 3.0 card - and download drivers?

Comment: Most workstations that have PCIe have USB 2.0. Most USB 3.0 cards are PCIe. Chances are though, if you have PCIe, you have USB 2.0. More details on your system would be useful tho.

Answer (score 1):

If your motherboard has PCI-E then you almost certainly have USB 2.0 as a minimum. In this case you should be able to buy a PCI-E USB 3 card in order to get a USB 3 port.

If you definitely only have USB 1.1 then you almost certainly do not have PCIE slots available. A machine that does **not** have USB 2 on it would predate PCI-E as well, in this case the best you could hope for is to get a PCI (not PCI-E) USB 2 card.

Either way you should be able to buy the relevant card and install the drivers to get the port you require.

---

Your [motherboard manual](http://m.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04136946) states you have both USB 2 and at least 3 PCI-E slots, so you should be able to install a USB 3 PCI-E card and simply install the drivers.